# Graph multiple datasets based on certain criteria from data split up between several dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, subset, with-statement

I have several dataframes each of which has data from multiple sources. I need to be able to plot data based on certain criteria. For instance I want to be able to plot all records where `season=="wet"` but that also have the criteria of `canopy_understory=="c"` from each dataframe on one plot, and use the `temp_sd` column of as an error bar. The data is structured in this particular way due to the way in which it was collected and what was assumed to be the most sensible way of parsing it.

My attempt to extract data using `with` has been:

```
with(valley_ls,temp_mean[season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c"])
with(valley_ls,hour[season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c"])
with(ridge_ls,temp_mean[season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c"])
with(ridge_ls,hour[season=="wet"&canopy_understory=="u"])
```

This gets me the `hour` or `temp_mean` that meet the criteria I want, but I need to be able to extract and plot, the `temp_mean` and the `temp_sd` as an error bar. I have attempted subsetting these out into new dataframes, but this is error prone and fraught.

An example of the plotting that I've done using the multiple dataframes is this:

```
ggplot(data=ridge_u_w_summary,aes(x = times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(data=ridge_u_w_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=means),colour="red")+
  geom_line(data = valley_u_w_summary,aes(x=times,y=means))+
  geom_errorbar(data=valley_u_w_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd))+
  geom_line(data = edge_u_w_summary,aes(x=times,y=means),colour="blue")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_errorbar(data=edge_u_w_summary,aes(ymin=means-sd,ymax=means+sd),colour="blue")+
  labs(x="Time",y=expression("Temperature in understory May to December *C"))
```

Which produces that graph that I want, something like this:
[image]

The scheme above works fine but is untenable for use with other data because of how easy it is to mess up splitting into many dataframes.
I want to be able to generate several graphs using these same dataframes based on different criteria.

dput of `dump(list="valley_ls",file="dump_valley")`
:

```
    valley_ls <-
structure(list(canopy_understory = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), season = c("dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
NA, "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", NA, "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", NA), hour = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, NA, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, NA), temp_mean = c(21.9729388942774, 21.9202365308804, 
21.5160349854227, 21.6135348226018, 21.1698250728863, 21.3997371879106, 
21.7561224489796, 23.4584756898817, 25.5064233576642, 27.1829172141919, 
28.0613372093023, 28.7192358366271, 29.0794202898551, 28.9577075098814, 
28.4787572254335, 27.3324538258575, 26.3749638205499, 25.0135883905013, 
24.0727930535456, 23.5505277044855, 22.8426917510854, 22.7254617414248, 
22.49001447178, 22.9443645083933, 23.8475672877847, 23.6520574162679, 
23.6787136294028, 23.4181818181818, 23.5110260336907, 23.3245229007634, 
23.7951145038168, 25.3284351145038, 25.8448854961832, 27.8920801526718, 
28.0074809160305, 28.9004770992366, 28.6725190839695, 28.6689408396947, 
28.1945038167939, 27.1498808956646, 26.8738131699847, 25.4554337464252, 
25.493415007657, 24.6676358436606, 24.7966309341501, 24.2493803622498, 
24.2797856049005, 24.0876998769988, NA, 23.1587893864013, 23.0023631840796, 
22.7586842105263, 22.6404228855721, 22.4468421052632, 22.4090796019901, 
22.6627140974967, 23.479202988792, 24.4139841688654, 25.2576059850374, 
25.9127799736495, 26.2339152119701, 26.4725, 26.4246882793017, 
26.1284403669725, 25.7063511830635, 25.3211764705882, 24.8449004975124, 
24.4806535947712, 24.1813432835821, 23.9767320261438, 23.7926616915423, 
23.5675816993464, 23.7533333333333, 24.1737847222222, 23.9264961636829, 
24.0318639798489, 23.716010230179, 23.8171284634761, 23.5848191543556, 
23.9746231155779, 24.5888436067244, 25.1335427135678, 25.9691288843607, 
26.2968592964824, 26.6237391747326, 26.7585427135678, 26.5575140091696, 
26.4639447236181, 25.9500254971953, 25.8959748427673, 25.2427332993371, 
25.3163727959698, 24.7879591836735, 24.8969773299748, 24.4647448979592, 
24.5764483627204, 24.2546432062561, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24.3333333333333, 0, 24.25, 0, 24.0166666666667, 
0, 24.1583333333333, 0, 25.4, 0, 26.2333333333333, 0, 27.2109375, 
0, 27.375, 0, 26.2946428571429, 0, 24.9107142857143, 0, 24.7142857142857, 
0, 24.475, 0, NA), temp_sd = c(7.10368938706592, 6.31619559434987, 
6.63273716936668, 5.98207526384219, 6.81785819259387, 6.09008468822777, 
6.42905917510137, 6.12792441805719, 5.89400673610928, 4.93074376846361, 
5.68493137940986, 4.53882099065438, 5.67276330328425, 4.86289494479903, 
5.0064903940218, 4.50620321541371, 5.23548052610922, 5.73166481558604, 
6.9423848917103, 6.25916235030702, 7.02150223339283, 6.63198273255056, 
6.30121694018913, 1.16737424849318, 0.974447902019749, 0.883662726834489, 
1.1694960633107, 1.00119820290862, 0.950686394394519, 0.960508895273812, 
1.02435507152398, 1.9800105189055, 1.77743259093255, 2.28365035950242, 
2.41005581403749, 2.52263637550233, 2.58958905490024, 2.48794401404523, 
2.37928117718197, 1.9660860877379, 1.79705886384754, 1.22734366140094, 
1.39948592913543, 0.874295812773333, 1.97436507929567, 0.831676233519675, 
1.18463655086496, 0.809942069607868, NA, 1.22357269970187, 1.3197350152676, 
1.37832968945031, 1.34012520382106, 1.34142100192936, 1.34726498418677, 
1.31592378988696, 1.28713308691543, 1.42138403898271, 1.70993228486995, 
2.07113789555289, 2.01605834952938, 2.08999601275536, 1.93479577003559, 
1.71785163242327, 1.58992997264445, 1.56194809778642, 1.4394673032447, 
1.37240648943917, 1.29257875472938, 1.31372428816748, 1.29167595764256, 
1.31947555529684, 1.55319421073715, 0.875684015185201, 0.885810900384003, 
0.968966012850972, 0.903583472065802, 0.929241275404384, 0.928693033054035, 
0.885940062806948, 0.812794500845774, 1.05374707833118, 1.20584906712117, 
1.52863738732854, 1.49350509511768, 1.764425507212, 1.4427075343768, 
1.50555166076425, 1.11778354361208, 1.10212019137791, 0.916392369153426, 
0.963107068443978, 0.845676581451727, 0.971090795785566, 0.855977353338137, 
0.980098036879563, 0.959837031977444, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.711303297442365, 0, 0.490990253030983, 0, 0.599230657553818, 
0, 0.512057009474903, 0, 1.95724387122008, 0, 1.75564565521254, 
0, 2.59194214104019, 0, 2.33853586673371, 0, 1.64200213656485, 
0, 0.903290687394742, 0, 0.498624481575437, 0, 0.668487097856047, 
0, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -135L), vars = list(quote(canopy_understory), 
    quote(season)), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("canopy_understory", 
"season", "hour", "temp_mean", "temp_sd"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

output of `dump(list="ridge_ls",file="dump_ridge")`

```
ridge_ls <-
structure(list(canopy_understory = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", 
"u", "u"), season = c("dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", NA, "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
"wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", 
NA), hour = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, NA, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, NA), .Label = c("[0,100]", "(100,200]", 
"(200,300]", "(300,400]", "(400,500]", "(500,600]", "(600,700]", 
"(700,800]", "(800,900]", "(900,1e+03]", "(1e+03,1.1e+03]", "(1.1e+03,1.2e+03]", 
"(1.2e+03,1.3e+03]", "(1.3e+03,1.4e+03]", "(1.4e+03,1.5e+03]", 
"(1.5e+03,1.6e+03]", "(1.6e+03,1.7e+03]", "(1.7e+03,1.8e+03]", 
"(1.8e+03,1.9e+03]", "(1.9e+03,2e+03]", "(2e+03,2.1e+03]", "(2.1e+03,2.2e+03]", 
"(2.2e+03,2.3e+03]", "(2.3e+03,2.4e+03]"), class = "factor"), 
    temp_mean = c(22.562356127285, 21.8575176589304, 22.2091712707182, 
    21.4594349142281, 21.8741436464088, 21.2627648839556, 22.5725966850829, 
    23.8943491422805, 26.5008830022075, 27.0156407669021, 28.582398239824, 
    28.2173562058527, 29.3534065934066, 28.4145454545455, 28.5924259055982, 
    26.9787878787879, 26.7398685651698, 24.8841253791709, 24.7435307017544, 
    23.5766430738119, 23.8053728070175, 22.9302325581395, 23.238048245614, 
    22.4414285714286, 21.217952694843, 20.0397517730496, 23.4641860465116, 
    19.8450354609929, 23.2626356589147, 19.7900423728814, 24.0725581395349, 
    21.725918079096, 26.9862015503876, 23.7948799435028, 28.9759689922481, 
    24.5474390674673, 29.5715838509317, 24.3418226774991, 28.5812111801242, 
    23.115411806292, 26.9599378881988, 21.66085572843, 25.3357142857143, 
    20.9439179632249, 24.6169517884914, 20.5703218960028, 24.1321928460342, 
    20.0532657657658, NA, 22.7831422791639, 22.5624888093107, 
    22.2762711864407, 22.232139659803, 21.9816550348953, 22.0190689346464, 
    22.0713858424726, 22.9452103849597, 23.977390438247, 25.0091397849462, 
    25.7459163346614, 26.1808968609865, 26.4856007944389, 26.529226618705, 
    26.3300893743793, 25.837376460018, 25.3583580613254, 24.7221422142214, 
    24.2077304261645, 23.820702070207, 23.5147817460317, 23.3325225225225, 
    23.065376984127, 22.8946456692913, 23.837513397642, 23.646668909825, 
    23.6674418604651, 23.4305079044736, 23.4649224806202, 23.2881367292225, 
    23.5646034816248, 24.3536863270777, 24.9369439071567, 25.8866957104558, 
    26.5365570599613, 26.7293565683646, 27.253488372093, 26.7179624664879, 
    27.0480620155039, 26.019235924933, 26.193786407767, 25.1097217566209, 
    25.2966990291262, 24.5485417365069, 24.6792233009709, 24.2033199195171, 
    24.2778210116732, 23.9984624846248, NA), temp_sd = c(2.73648774464832, 
    3.89501902764261, 1.17914861593683, 3.84962929916136, 1.21627739822434, 
    3.843890078235, 1.48694927255381, 4.53475560968754, 2.4692449230815, 
    5.31072172311035, 2.7801646331622, 5.60552770772567, 3.00665642895969, 
    5.37991344736766, 2.54329494228649, 4.9109846279159, 2.01316086028232, 
    4.31184236532998, 1.40152881522735, 3.98898666713388, 1.17969636144613, 
    3.85727479873907, 1.1230885583311, 3.52267091349933, 7.52465558906129, 
    8.51904516252295, 0.89825806034385, 8.44060231674709, 0.894435454152911, 
    8.40140354279228, 0.954983885810659, 9.28188638752829, 2.08714908301206, 
    10.2555288869657, 2.55244904907137, 10.6329140791161, 2.78976411219072, 
    10.5641962864403, 2.62101883698402, 9.99645036090208, 2.06715648209951, 
    9.26879044865175, 1.22008755481441, 8.9245381254764, 0.956910613039714, 
    8.76186042815369, 0.872979293848191, 8.86368969220654, NA, 
    1.07371319492319, 1.09881749779836, 1.21307549226642, 1.2598629477623, 
    1.31286527191395, 1.36683838145348, 1.4137155267231, 1.42622231911717, 
    1.67860763496765, 1.79425260160877, 2.07042827387483, 2.10731458932958, 
    2.25919838602871, 2.13163564157989, 2.00443799155384, 1.78306510492528, 
    1.6813351820614, 1.41841025766038, 1.31504560496238, 1.16441372650497, 
    1.13358486644718, 1.04842014209596, 1.04971819964, 1.03129409017733, 
    0.781095011320959, 0.81578111612132, 0.84436800431466, 0.852579597106629, 
    0.861309791588296, 0.900921426522036, 0.850538183149708, 
    0.86563230808076, 1.13990715262908, 1.29807379664268, 1.71755587993833, 
    1.64101678624236, 1.995102606277, 1.63987330277186, 1.83556454743413, 
    1.35735241712701, 1.49013625660173, 1.02009949230349, 1.07160411808372, 
    0.800509386066778, 0.854705093200672, 0.765802355814258, 
    0.819364989149883, 0.77707386292288, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -98L), vars = list(
    quote(canopy_understory), quote(season)), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("canopy_understory", 
"season", "hour", "temp_mean", "temp_sd"))
```

Comment: Your dput objects are not working for me. But this seems like a data structuring issue. You can probably get what you want by first getting your data in a tidy format. See http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html

Comment: I hadn't intended the plot to be actually run with the dputs just to show what I had done previously

Comment: Right. Generally dput is used to share the data but I get an error when running your dput code so I can't actually play with what I presumed was the example data.

Comment: I see. The dput is the example data, I just hadn't intended people to try to use the ggplot. I'll try to get a useable dput when I get back to my system.

Comment: I added what is a hopefully more easily reproducible dataset.

Answer (score 0):

What I ultimately did was to create subsets of each condition that I wanted to graph. This is not as elegant as I wanted, but it does work.

```
valley_dry_canopy_subset <-subset(valley_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c")
valley_wet_canopy_subset <-subset(valley_ls,season=="wet"&canopy_understory=="c")
valley_dry_understory_subset <-subset(valley_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="u")
valley_wet_understory_subset <-subset(valley_ls,season=="wet"&canopy_understory=="u")

ridge_dry_canopy_subset <-subset(ridge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c")
ridge_wet_canopy_subset <-subset(ridge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c")
ridge_dry_understory_subset <-subset(ridge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="u")
ridge_wet_understory_subset <-subset(ridge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="u")

edge_dry_canopy_subset <-subset(edge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c")
edge_wet_canopy_subset <-subset(edge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="c")
edge_dry_understory_subset <-subset(edge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="u")
edge_wet_understory_subset <-subset(edge_ls,season=="dry"&canopy_understory=="u")
```

One of the plots can be graphed like this:

```
ggplot(data=na.omit(valley_wet_canopy_subset),aes(x = hour,y=temp_mean))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=temp_mean-temp_sd,ymax=temp_mean+temp_sd),colour="black")+
   geom_line(aes(y=temp_mean),colour="black",size=1)+
   geom_errorbar(data=ridge_wet_canopy_subset,aes(ymin=temp_mean-temp_sd,ymax=temp_mean+temp_sd),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=temp_mean),colour="black",size=1)+
  geom_errorbar(data=edge_wet_canopy_subset,aes(ymin=temp_mean-temp_sd,ymax=temp_mean+temp_sd),colour="blue")+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Time",y="Temperature in canopy May to December")
```